# Printing the text from json in python (Printing Specific Field from json)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print specific field from json document. ie. I want to print the 'text' alone from the json.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('/home/soundarya/soundarya/sound1.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

# for item in data[:5]:
#   pprint(data['text'])

# for dat in data: 
#   print(data[0:5])
for d in data[:5]:
    print data
    print (data['text'])

soundarya@soundarya:~/Desktop/python practice$ python page.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page.py", line 13, in <module>
    print data['text']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

from each element in the json, I want to print the Text alone.

in json.. each element in the list is a dictionary

can anyone help over here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should try using `literal_eval()` on the json string, instead of using the json package. It should create the data structure for you, just like in JS

Comment: you should use `d['text']` not `data['text']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the items within data are dictionary so you need to change `data['text']` to `d['text']`:

```
for d in data[:5]:
    print d
    print (d['text'])
```